# Can't refresh DataTables after ajax table update

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using ajax form to filter data in my table tbody. The problem is when I try to sort data after filter by clicking on column header cell, the old data appears. For example, I have table like this:

```
=========================================
| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
=========================================
|  data11 |  data12 | data13  | data14  |
|  data21 |  data22 | data23  | data24  |
|  data31 |  data32 | data33  | data34  |
|  data41 |  data42 | data43  | data44  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I'm filtering data and I've got this:

```
=========================================
| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
=========================================
|  data11 |  data12 | data13  | data14  |
|  data41 |  data42 | data43  | data44  |
-----------------------------------------
```

But when I click on `header1` to sort the data descending, the old data shows up:

```
=========================================
| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
=========================================
|  data41 |  data42 | data43  | data44  |
|  data31 |  data32 | data33  | data34  |
|  data21 |  data22 | data23  | data24  |
|  data11 |  data12 | data13  | data14  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I've tried many ways to fix this. In my `OnComplete` action I've tried to reinitialise the datatable with

```
$('#data').dataTable().fnDestroy()
$('#data').dataTable({myoptions})
```

or redraw it:

```
var myTable = $("#data").dataTable({ bRetrieve: true });
myTable.fnDraw();
```

but nothing works.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

UPDATE:
Some code I use:
Form used to update table

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { 
    LoadingElementId = "loading-bar", 
    UpdateTargetId = "assetsView", 
    Url = Url.Action("GetElementList"), 
    HttpMethod = "Get", 
    OnComplete = "OnComplete" 
}))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Status", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(f => filters.AssetStatusID, ViewBag.AssetStatusID as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Status", Multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(f => filters.AssetStatusID)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Zastosuj" class="btn btn-grey" />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-grey">Anuluj</a>
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#data').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false
        //"aoColumnDefs": [
        //    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [6] }
        //]
    });
    oTable.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]);
    oFH = new FixedHeader(oTable, {
        "offsetTop": 131
    });
});

function OnComplete(request, status) {
    var table = $("#data").dataTable({ bRetrieve: true });
    table.fnDraw();
    oFH.fnUpdate();
}
```

HTML (fragment with table):

```
<div class="table">
<table id="data" class="data-table table-fixed-header">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetTypeID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturerID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SAPNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserEmployeeID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocalizationID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusID)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="assetsView">
        @Html.Action("GetElementList", new { filters = filters })
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

GetElementsList function:

```
public override ActionResult GetElementList(AssetFilter filters)
    {
        //some filtering stuff

        return PartialView("_AssetsView", assets.OrderBy(a => a.ITNumber).ToList());
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us the code you're using so we can give you a full answer

Comment: Can't see data, assetsView or myTable that are all mentioned in your code you've posted. At a random guess what ever the method/action you're using to sort doesn't also include any already applied filtering, so when you try and sort it removes the filtering

Comment: Shouldn't this be set to `true`: `"bFilter": false,`?

Comment: @Raidri no, because I don't want to use built-in search field. I use my own ajax function to replace data in table.

Comment: @matt_lethargic I've added code you were talking about. Do you have any idea what's wrong?